# Can you help me with "Reason why s + v / Reason to ~" sentence pattern

Tags: sentence-construction

I'd like to say there's not any reason why I go to a bank because I always use internet banking. In this situation, Can I say like this?

> 1. I don't have any reasons to go to a bank.

***To infinitive*** is modifying ***a reason***, and I think it is right.

> 2. I don't have a reason I have to go to a bank.

***Clause( I have to go to a bank)*** is modifying ***a reason***, and I think it's right.

> 3. There's not any reason for me to go to a bank.

***For ~ to infinitive*** is modifying ***any reason*** and I think it's right.

Am I right to think this way?

Comment: In "1" *to go to a bank* is the infinitive phrase used as an adjective.  The "2" has the omitted *according to which* ("a reason *according to which* I have to...).  The example 3 is essentially the same as 1, I think.  All are acceptable.

Comment: Can we use  " is no reason"  instead of '' is not any '' ?

Comment: and what about: "I do not see any reasons to go to a bank"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't have any reasons to go to a bank.

**I don't have any *reason* to go to a bank.**

> I don't have a reason I have to go to a bank.

*I have no reason to go to a bank.*

> There's not any reason for me to go to a bank.

**There's no reason for me to go to a bank.**